# GCP Project Migration Option Unavailable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, migration

Hello Google Cloud Experts,

I was recently trying to get a Google Cloud Platform project that is seperate from our organization projects migrated/movbed into our organization.

I am having some issues where both the migrate button on the 'manage resources' page is greyed out, telling me to select a project that is not part of an organization, which I have and where, and when selecting the project and clicking the 'move' option does not show my organization as an option for me to move the project into.

Screenshot of what is happening: [Google Cloud Platform 'Manage Resources' page with greyed-out migration button][1]

I understand that I will need the proper permissions to migrate projects, and I seem to have all the permissions as shown here: https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration

Could I be missing something? Is there another place I should look? I have done this before a few times with out issues, so I am curious to know if there is something specific about THIS project that is restricting the migration/move.

Let me know when you can what you would suggest I try and reach out if you need more information to assist me with this.

Thank you team,

Comment: Unfortunately, your screenshot isn't available.

Answer (score 4):

you probably don't have the error anymore but since I've seen the same bug today, I'll give a workaround.

So basically the problem is that the migration button stays grayed our because the organization is already filled in.
What you need is to do is the following :

- go top left and click on google cloud platform
- Click on the project selection menu next to "google cloud platform"
- In the window that opens, select "no organization" at the top of your screen and then select your project you want to migrate in the menu.
- Go back to the manage ressources tab and you'll be able to migrate your project because you'll be able to select (for real) the organization to which you want to migrate and that grays out the migration button.

Answer (score 0):

To migrate separate project into existing organization you should follow documentation [Migrating Projects into an Organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing) section [Migrating projects with no organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_projects_with_no_organization):

> To migrate a project, you will need the Project Creator role
>   (`roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator`) on the organization to which
>   you want to migrate your project. You will also need the Project Mover
>   role (`roles/resourcemanager.projectMover`) on the project you are
>   migrating. **If you don't have these roles, the target organization
>   won't appear in the Google Cloud Console as a choice for migration**.

So, **the cause of your issue** "Google Cloud Platform 'Manage Resources' page with greyed-out migration button" is that **you don't have all the required permissions**.

In adition, keep in mind that:

> **Project migration isn't reversible.** After a project is associated with an organization, you can't change it back to No organization or
>   move it to another organization on your own. If you want to move a
>   project after it's associated with an organization, contact [Google
>   Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support).

Comment: Yes, as reported above, I have both of those required permissions as well as others that I have added to troubleshoot. Still, the issue persists.

Comment: Do you have required roles in both project and organization?

Comment: roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator on the organization and roles/resourcemanager.projectMover on the project

Yes.

Comment: Please update your question with missed screenshot. Do you use the same account in both projects?

Answer (score 0):

I also just ran into this problem, the "Migrate" button was greyed out even though I am the organization admin and the project owner.

The solution in my case was to use `gcloud` to perform the migrations, and it worked, it involved a few commands to find out my organization ID and the project ID, one command to perform the actual move, then I had to approve one confirmation prompt, and it was done with no issues.

The commands are the ones specified here [Migrating Projects / Perform the Migration](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration#perform_migration)

And here they are:

```
gcloud beta organizations list

gcloud beta projects list

gcloud beta projects move PROJECT_ID --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
```